# How to retrieve Instagram followers' locations?

Tags: instagram

I've searched through the topics but it seems that exactly this questions hadn't been asked yet.

Could anyone, please, share their opinion on how to retrieve an Instagram account  followers' posts locations in order to map them after that on one map?

On the account there are around 2000-2100 followers.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to get the location of every post of all 2000 followers?

Comment: Thank you for the question. Yes, I do. Please, share your ideas if you have a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get detailed user information from instagram you have to use the `GET /users/user-id` endpoint.

So to get the location information for all an accounts followers you have to use 
`GET/users/user-id/followed-by` and iterate through the results.

Be careful. Instagram api limit is currently 5000 requests per hour. Accounts with more followers than that you will have to use some form of queue

Edit: just seen you want the post locations:

Similar method, excite instead of `GET /users/user-id` user `GET /users/user-id/recent` and grab the locations of the media. Note in my experience the location function is used very little by instagram users. I once pulled 3000 media that had only 20 media with a location

Comment: Dear AndyRyan, thank you for a detailed answer I'm from Central Asia, surprisingly enough (for me as well) I see users quite often use location function when posting :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just location of a user using APIs, there are couple ways you can guess the location, by looking for bio information and check if they have any location specified or you can check location of all the photos posted by a user and kind of guess the location by analyzing where most of the photos are being posted at.

you can use the API `/users/user-id/recent` to get all the photos from a user and look for location property in API response and map it on google map.

you can use http://gramfeed.com to see user photos with a map of photo locations, you will have to do this for each user and determine the location.

Comment: Dear Krisrak , thank you. But you see, there is no option on that online service to map all the posts of 2000 followers at the same time or is there?